# How do I center my drawing and matrices horizontally and vertically inside a table in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, equations

I have some drawings and matrices in written in Latex and I want to write them in tabular form. The problem is I am unable to center them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

%PLEASE IGNORE IT. THIS IS FOR DRAWING
\newcommand{\AxisRotator}[1][rotate=0]{%
    \tikz [x=0.25cm,y=0.60cm,line width=.2ex,-stealth,#1] \draw (0,0) arc (-150:150:1 and 1);%
}


%DRAWING IN LATEX
\def\x{\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm,z=0.3cm,>=stealth]
\draw[->] (xyz cs:x=0) -- (xyz cs:x=5) node[above] {$z$};
\draw[rotate=15][->] (xyz cs:x=0) -- (xyz cs:x=5) node[above] {$z1$};

\draw[->] (xyz cs:y=0) --(xyz cs:y=5) node[right] {$x$};

\draw[->] (xyz cs:z=0) --(xyz cs:z=-5) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[rotate=15][->] (xyz cs:z=0) --(xyz cs:z=-5) node[above] {$y1$};
\draw (0,0)  -- (0,3)  node [midway] {\AxisRotator[rotate=-90]};
\draw (1,3) node {\(\phi\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newpage

%MY TABLE STARTS FROM HERE
\begin{table} 
\begin{center}

\caption{Euler Elemental Rotations}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{5cm}|p{6cm}|}
    \hline
    Axis & Euler Elemental Rotation & Rotation Matrix\\
    \hline 
    x axis & \x & \(R_x(\phi) = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 &cos\phi& -sin\phi \\
    0 &sin\phi &cos\phi
    \end{bmatrix} \) \\
    \hline 

    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I center everything in my table vertically and horizontally?

Comment: Unrelated to the alignment of elements inside of table cells, but probably nevertheless something to consider: Using the `center` environment inside of a `table` environment adds additional white space, which you might want to avoid. To nevertheless horizontally center the table within the textwidth, you may want to remove the `center` environment and use `\centering` instead. For an improved spacing between caption and table, you may want to use the `caption` package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `p` column type aligns cell contents vertically along the topmost common baseline across all rows. In the case of a `tikzpicture` object, though, the one and only "baseline" by default is placed at the *bottom* of the object. Hence, in your example, it looks like the three cells are actually aligned at the bottom, and not at either the top or middle.

I can think of two ways of achieving your formatting objective.

- You could use the `m` column type instead of `p`. E.g., replace

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{5cm}|p{6cm}|}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}|m{5cm}|m{6cm}|}
  ```

  Note: In order to use the `m` column type, the `array` package must be loaded. Happily, that's is the case in your test document.
- You could keep the `p` column type but modify the setup of the `tikzpicture` environment, so that the object's notional baseline is placed at the center rather than at the bottom of the object. One way to do this is to add the option `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` to the optional argument of the `tikzpicture` environment. E.g., change

  ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm,z=0.3cm,>=stealth]
  ```

  to

  ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm,z=0.3cm,>=stealth,
                       baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  ```