# Trying to vertically matrices inside a table, and fix a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I've been trying to create a table which contains a few different figures as well as some matrices, but I have been having trouble trying to centre the matrices inside the table, and trying to fix the labels I have created for my cube. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,decorations.markings,hobby}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}
\date{March 2021}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}
\doublespacing
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\let\vec\mathbf
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{Algebraic branching program} &
    \multirow{Adjacency matrix} &
    \multirow{Determinant of adjacency matrix}\\         \hline
   \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill,red] (6.05, 2.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill,red] (6.05, 1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (6,2) -- (6,1)
    node [midway,right] {$x_{11}$};
  \end{tikzpicture} & \abovebaseline[-3pt]{\begin{pmatrix}
x_{11}\\
\end{pmatrix}}  & $\text{det}(A)=x_{11}$  \\
    \hline
      \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.35 with {\arrow{>}}}] 

\draw[fill,red] (1.55, 1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (0.55, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;

\draw[fill] (2.55, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;

\draw[fill,red] (1.55, -1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;

\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,1) -- (0.5,0) 
    node [midway,left] {$x_{11}$};

\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,1) -- (2.5,0)
    node [midway,right] {$x_{21}$};

\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (0.5,0) -- (1.5,-1)
    node [midway,left] {$x_{22}$};


\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (2.5,0) -- (1.5,-1)
    node [midway,right] {$x_{12}$};

\draw (0.5, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.2) -- cycle;

\draw (2.9, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.2) -- cycle;



\end{tikzpicture}  & 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12}\\
x_{21} & x_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}  & $\text{det}(A)=x_{11}x_{22}+x_{12}x_{21}$\\  
    \hline
     \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.35 with {\arrow{>}}}
] 

\draw[fill,red] (1.55, 1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (0.55, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (1.55, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (2.55, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (0.55, -1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (1.55, -1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (2.55, -1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill,red] (1.55, -2.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;

\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,1) -- (0.5,0) 
    node [midway,left] {$x_{11}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,1) -- (1.5,0)
    node [pos=0.65,right] {$x_{12}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,1) -- (2.5,0)
    node [pos=0.5,right] {$x_{13}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (0.5,0) -- (0.5,-1)
    node [midway,left] {$x_{22}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (0.5,0) -- (1.5,-1)
    node [midway, right] {$x_{23}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,0) -- (0.5,-1)
    node [pos=0.3,above] {$x_{21}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,0) -- (2.5,-1)
    node [] {$x_{23}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (2.5,0) -- (2.5,-1)
    node [midway,right] {$x_{22}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (2.5,0) -- (1.5,-1)
    node [pos=0.85,right] {$x_{21}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (0.5,-1) -- (1.5,-2) 
    node [midway,left] {$x_{33}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,-1) -- (1.5,-2)
    node [pos=0.2,left] {$x_{32}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (2.5,-1) -- (1.5,-2)
    node [midway,right] {$x_{31}$};
\end{tikzpicture} & \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix} & $\text{det}(A)= x_{33}x_{22}x_{11}+...$  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
 \caption{Comparison of ABP for the case of n=1,2,3} 
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

This produces the following output

[image]

However, I would like to try and make it so that the edge labels are clearly visible on the cube, and not crossing over any lines, and so that columns 2 and 3 are centered in the middle.

Comment: I think this link is useful for you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603555/24644

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! To center vertically, you may try using the `m` column from the `array` package.

Comment: thankyou very much!

Answer (score 5):

You can set the baseline of your `tikzpicture`s appropriately. For your convenience I added a style, `vcenter tikz`, which introduces an appropriate node and sets the baseline accordingly. (Now the code is somewhat more minimal but one could reduce it further. Also, use `\det` instead of `\text{det}`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\title{598 Final report}
\author{owen.doty }
\date{March 2021}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}
\doublespacing
\tikzset{vcenter tikz/.style={execute at end picture={%
 \path (current bounding box.center) node (TMP) {\vphantom{T}};
    },baseline={(TMP.base)}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Algebraic branching program &
    Adjacency matrix &
    Determinant of adjacency matrix\\         \hline
   \begin{tikzpicture}[vcenter tikz]
\draw[fill,red] (6.05, 2.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill,red] (6.05, 1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (6,2) -- (6,1)
    node [midway,right] (x11) {$x_{11}$};
  \end{tikzpicture} & $\begin{pmatrix}
        x_{11}\\
        \end{pmatrix}$  & $\det(A)=x_{11}$  \\
    \hline
      \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[vcenter tikz,decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.35 with {\arrow{>}}}] 
\draw[fill,red] (1.55, 1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (0.55, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;

\draw[fill] (2.55, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;

\draw[fill,red] (1.55, -1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;

\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,1) -- (0.5,0) 
    node [midway,left] {$x_{11}$};

\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,1) -- (2.5,0)
    node [midway,right] {$x_{21}$};

\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (0.5,0) -- (1.5,-1)
    node [midway,left] {$x_{22}$};


\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (2.5,0) -- (1.5,-1)
    node [midway,right] {$x_{12}$};

\draw (0.5, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.2) -- cycle;

\draw (2.9, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.2) -- cycle;



\end{tikzpicture}  & 
$\begin{pmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12}\\
x_{21} & x_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}$  & $\det(A)=x_{11}x_{22}+x_{12}x_{21}$\\  
    \hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[vcenter tikz,decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.35 with {\arrow{>}}}
] 

\draw[fill,red] (1.55, 1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (0.55, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (1.55, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (2.55, 0.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (0.55, -1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (1.55, -1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (2.55, -1.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;
\draw[fill,red] (1.55, -2.0) arc(0:360:0.05) -- cycle;

\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,1) -- (0.5,0) 
    node [midway,left] {$x_{11}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,1) -- (1.5,0)
    node [pos=0.65,right] {$x_{12}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,1) -- (2.5,0)
    node [pos=0.5,right] {$x_{13}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (0.5,0) -- (0.5,-1)
    node [midway,left] {$x_{22}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (0.5,0) -- (1.5,-1)
    node [midway, right] {$x_{23}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,0) -- (0.5,-1)
    node [pos=0.3,above] {$x_{21}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,0) -- (2.5,-1)
    node [] {$x_{23}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (2.5,0) -- (2.5,-1)
    node [midway,right] {$x_{22}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (2.5,0) -- (1.5,-1)
    node [pos=0.85,right] {$x_{21}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (0.5,-1) -- (1.5,-2) 
    node [midway,left] {$x_{33}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (1.5,-1) -- (1.5,-2)
    node [pos=0.2,left] {$x_{32}$};
\draw[thick,black,postaction={decorate}] (2.5,-1) -- (1.5,-2)
    node [midway,right] {$x_{31}$};
\end{tikzpicture} & $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$ & $\det(A)= x_{33}x_{22}x_{11}+\dots$  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
 \caption{Comparison of ABP for the case of $n=1,2,3$.} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou very much! This solves alot of my issues :)